# get a list of key words from a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, and one column contains the string description of movies in Danish:

```
df.Description.tail()

24756    Der er nye kendisser i rundkredsen, nemlig Ski...
24757    Hvad fÃ¥r man, hvis man blander en gruppe af k...
24758    Hvordan vÃ¦lter man en minister? Hvordan Ã¸del...
24759    Der er dÃ¸mt mandehygge i hulen hos ZULUs tera...
24760    Kender du de dage pÃ¥ arbejdet, hvor alt bare ...
```

I first check that all the values of the column `Description` are strings:
`df.applymap(type).eq(str).all()`

```
Video.ID.v26    False
Title            True
Category        False
Description      True
dtype: bool
```

What I want is to create another column which contains the words found in each string, separated with a , like this:

```
24756   [Der, er, nye, kendisser, i, rundkredsen, ...
```

In my loop, I also use Rake() to delete Danish stop words. Here is my loop:

```
# initializing the new column
df['Key_words'] = ""

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plot = row['Description']

    # instantiating Rake, by default is uses english stopwords from NLTK, but we want Danish
    # and discard all puntuation characters
    r = Rake('da')

    # extracting the words by passing the text
    r.extract_keywords_from_text(plot)

    # getting the dictionary whith key words and their scores
    key_words_dict_scores = r.get_word_degrees()

    # assigning the key words to the new column
    row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys())
```

The problem is that the new column `Key_words` is empty...

`df.Key_words.tail()`

```
24756    
24757    
24758    
24759    
24760    
Name: Key_words, dtype: object
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of df.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not
>   guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
>   iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
>   effect.

In your case, this combination of lines is the problem:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():  # row is generated
    [...]
    row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys()) # row is modified
```

If you want to use iterrows, you could circumvent situations like the above, for instance by storing intermediate data in a list, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

# make dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5)})

#initialise list
new_entries = []

# do iterrows, and operations on entries in row
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    new_entries.append(2* row['a'])  # store intermediate data in list

df['b'] = new_entries # assign temp data to new column
```

One other piece of advice: I had to generate my own dataframe to illustrate my solution, because the format in which you posted your data does not allow easy import/copying. please check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) to be able to ask better formulated questions.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I would never imagine that you can't manipulate the row of an iteration. And sorry for not posting by creating a dataframe first, you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

Use apply

```
def my_keyword_func(row):
    plot = row['Description']
    ....
    return ['key word 1', 'key word 2']
df['Key_words'] = df.apply(my_keyword_func, axis=1)
```